# How can I make so that the order of this loop's output is random?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, my `taxonomy-product-category.php` template has the following loop for loading posts into the page:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

However, I want the posts to be randomly ordered rather than following a specific order like date added.

How can I modify this loop to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to set random ordering to your taxonomy pages. Just note, random ordering duplicates posts between paged pages as each page is a new query and not an extension to one. This is unfortunately how random ordering works.

You can try the following

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only targets the front end
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only targets the main query
         && $q->is_tax( 'product-category' ) // Only targets the product-category tax pages
    ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => YOUR CATEGORY ID,
    'post_type' => YOUR CUSTOM POST TYPE,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: would love an explanation for the downvote, been using this method for years.

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for the answer. I must mention something though. Normally, my mainpage shows only a CPT. This taxonomy is also supposed to show only CPT posts. Even though loop has no parameter explicitly implying this, the loop still is managing to load only CPT posts. However when I tried your method (or query_posts() by myself) then it loads normal posts into the page and not CPT. Any ideas about that?

Comment: That is why you must **never** change the main query with a custom one, they lead to even more issues ;-)

Comment: also, there are many a resource explaining why you should use a new WP_query object over query_posts, here's just one example: http://www.techjunkie.com/wp_query-query_posts-get_posts/

Comment: There is also enough resources explaining why you should use `pre_get_posts` above a new `WP_Query` to alter the main query

Comment: as @PieterGoosen said, this can lead to issues, but if you remember to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop, all should be fine.

Comment: You are rerunning what the main query already does, which means that you are running twice as much queries which leads to a slower page load which leads to a low ranking on google and other search engines. **OPTIMIZATION**

Comment: Sadly, I bought this theme and didn't design it myself. Is it okay if I invite you guys to a chat page and you help me figure it out? I am new to Wordpress.

Comment: No shame in admitting that @PieterGoosen's answer is probably the better way to go in this case.

Comment: @WheatBeak He also helped a lot in the chat with additional problems as well. Still, thanks for your answer a lot. It is just that my case is rather unordinary.